# I like it when it snows/it's snowing

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Which one is the right choice in the sentence?

> I like it when it snows/is snowing.

If both are correct and the tense depends on the context what is the difference?

Comment: Based on the title of the question it sounds like you know this, but I'd add that "when it snows" and "when it's snowing" both sound like idiomatic conversational English to me, but if you said "when it is snowing" without the contraction, that would be very unnatural in speech.

Comment: Both are fine, and have near enough the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When it snows** refers to the weather event as a weather event, as occasions of such.  You like snowy days. Maybe you like the fact that school is cancelled when the snowfall is heavy.

**When it is snowing** refers to the weather event as an event-in-progress. You like it when the snow comes down from the sky and fills the air with snowflakes. Something about the falling snow pleases you.